# How do you set the default reviewer for a Pull Request?

Tags: azure-devops

Not sure SO is the right place or this question but couldn't see any other stack exchange site that this would suit. So, in VSTS how do you change the default team / reviewer when a pull request is created?

***Update***
This appears to be set by the project/team selected at the top, not the repo. So if you select teamA at the top, but have a repo not related to that team the PR will default the reviewer as teamA, which isn't ideal.

Comment: When creating a PR, you can specify the team/group/user as the reviews. So what do you mean " change the default team / reviewer" for a PR?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT - At the moment we have a default project team set when raising a PR. However, now we've created a new repo and project so we want to change the default team reviews go to. No one seem to remember how to change this. Should this happen by default?

Comment: With the new navigation, you should be able to create pull request without a default team as reviewer. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 23):

Check the answer to this question: [Branch Policy: Require atleast 1 Approval from specified approvers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51644674/branch-policy-require-atleast-1-approval-from-specified-approvers/51645052#51645052).

You specify which reviewers to add automatically as part of the branch policies:
[image]

If you mark the group as required someone from that group has to approve the PR, else they will simply be added and notified but anyone can approve the PR (even the person who created it depending on your settings).

Comment: From further investigation and the answers I've got here it looks like there's currently no real way of setting a default reviewer for a PR. This is probably the closest I'll get to what I need though so +1, but it still adds the project team as a reviewer irrespective of the repo I've selected. Maybe there's something I can do about that so that doesn't happen by default rather than look to set a default.

Comment: You could setup a dedicated team and even filter that team by path in you sources...

Comment: Is there a way to set this at the organization level so that it applies to all projects?

Comment: Thank you for that! giosh. Why is this setting so hidden lol ?

Answer (score 1):

The reviewers in the **dropdown list only shows the team/group/user you are recently specified** (ordered by time and it’s not default reviewers).

[image]

If you want to specify team/group/user as the PR reviewers which are not shown in the dropdown list, you can search related name, it will show the team/group/user you are looking for.

Such as I want to specify `teamA` as the PR reviewers, just input `teamA` and click search (or press enter), it will show the `teamA`, and you can specify `teamA` as PR reviewers.

[image]

[image]

And when you specify reviewers for next time, teamA will shown on the top of the dropdown list.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but it's not quite what I'm looking for. At the moment, when I create a PR the selected Project Team is defaulted as the reviewer. So if I've selected 'ProjectA' as the project at the top of the page but I'm creating a PR for 'ProjectB' the reviewer will already be set to 'TeamA'. I don't need to search for anything. However, this seems silly as I could be in a repo that's not related to that project. So, is there a way of setting the default reviewer based on a repo?

Comment: @sr28 it's reasonable to show different teams, projects as reviewers since PR reviewers not always exist in the same team or project. And if you want to remove a team/group/users from dropdown list, just delete as the example shows https://ibb.co/hzR1Jz.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the last version of VSTS [creates a PR without a default team as reviewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/release-notes/2018/jul-10-vsts#create-pull-requests-without-a-default-team-as-reviewer).